# Create new element with fixed value and dynamic attribute using xslt

Tags: xslt

if i'm trying to understand xslt where i'm stuck at a place where i want to add an element with a fixed value and a dynamic attribute

input:

```
<newsItem parentGUID="fakeGuid">
</newsItem>
```

desired output:

```
<newsItem>
  <parent Key="fakeGuid">News</parent>
<newsItem>
```

Current Xslt (value isn't in the actual output)

```
<xsl:template match="NewsItem">
  <xsl:element name="Parent">
      <xsl:attribute name="Key">
        <xsl:value-of select="@parentGUID"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="News"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Can someone point me out what i'm doing wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: A general comment: If you want to create an element named Parent and that is statically known, just use `<parent>` instead of `<xsl:element name="parent">` (unless you just really like typing and making the XSLT harder to read). Generally, the only time to use `xsl:element` is if the name is dynamically constructed.

Comment: Note that XML is case-sensitive: `<xsl:template match="NewsItem">` will NOT match `<newsItem>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="News"/>
```

looks for a child element named `News` to extract its string-value. To output the literal text "News", try:

```
<xsl:text>News</xsl:text>
```

---

Note also that you don't need to use `xsl:element` to create a literal result element. To get the result you show, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="newsItem">
    <xsl:copy>
        <Parent key="{@parentGUID}">News</Parent>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Read about [attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#attribute-value-templates) to understand how this works.